# Are Gradle's `latest.release` and native locking feature compatible

Tags: gradle

I am using [Gradle's native locking mechanism](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_locking.html) for all the modules in my project and most of my dependencies are declared with `latest.release` version.

Everything was fine until someday CI became broken because of one the libraries have got an update, hence a new version has become available. And that led my Gradle build to fail with an exception:

```
Execution failed for task ':modules:...:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':modules:application:compileClasspath'.
   > Did not resolve 'com.x.y:z:2.14.0' which has been forced / substituted to a different version: '2.15.0-rc1'
```

This library is declared as described below:

```
implemenetation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:latest.release')
```

So why the lockfile is ignored? Is `latest.release` version constraint compatible with Gradle locking mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Found an issue on GitHub.

It's related to `https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/258`.